# Character with wedges over and under

Tags: math-mode, accents

How can I have this character, I need f and U ?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A combination of [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `\overset` and `\underset` can help here:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\newcommand{\hatv}[1]{\overset{\wedge}{\underset{\vee}{\mathstrut#1}}}
\newcommand{\fhatv}{\hatv{f}}
\newcommand{\Uhatv}{\hatv{U}}
\begin{document}
$\fhatv\ \Uhatv$
\end{document}
```

The use of `\mathstrut` allows for comparable baselines when using characters with different depths or heights.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\[
\mathop{f{}}\limits_\vee^\wedge
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works great with excatly your code but not in the following :\[
\beta_f =\frac{  \mathop{f{}}_\vee^\wedge  }{f_r} \times 100
\]

Comment: You need `\limits` before the `_` if you want them always in over/under position. By default mathop subscripts move to subscript position inline.

Comment: This is a bit OT, but can anyone comment on the possibility/usefulness of dropping unicode decimal definitions directly into *TeX code, and TeX's (e.g. `fontspec`'s) ability to parse them.  For example, the unicode for an `f` with a circumflex above it and a caron below it is `f&#812;&#770;`.  (See my example answer below.)

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example to explore the possibility/usefulness of direct unicode input.  I think David Carlisle's answer is perfect.

f̬̂ Û̬

Comment: I think that Unicode input for TeX generally and math in particular is fine but I think that you should preserve the distinction between textual diacritics and math operators that happen to be in those positions. Unicode combining characters are the former.  this is presumably denoting some operation with <> brackets but vertical and you should use the same nottaion whether the base is a single letter or a n expression or a non-letter construct such as a box. You can not do that with combining characters.

Comment: Agree 100%.  Also, just answered my own question by copying and pasting the diacriticked U above into my source.  XeLaTeX just gave me a "U" back.